# docker-compose secrets without swarm mode: how to import their values?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, secrets

There are some questions about using secrets with `docker-compose` without swarm mode, but when trying to follow some of them, I never managed to read the secrets inside running container.

#### Approach #1

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.8"

services:
  server:
    image: alpine:latest
    secrets:
      - sec-str
    environment:
      - TE_STR=${sec-str}
    command: tail -F .

secrets:
  sec-str:
    file: ./secret.s
```

`secret.s`:

```
sec-str="A!Bit@complicated-String^%"
```

Outcome:

```bash
/ # echo $TE_STR
str
```

#### Approach #2

Only change is made here, in `secret.s`:

```
"A!Bit@complicated-String^%"
```

Outcome:

```bash
/ # echo $TE_STR
str
```

#### Approach #3

`TE_STR=${sec-str}` replaced with `TE_STR=$sec-str`.

Outcome:

```bash
/ # echo $TE_STR
-str
```

Running out of ideas for now. Any clues from you?

Answer (score 0):

Secrets are still files inside the container.
You can find yours at:

```
/run/secrets/sec-str
```

If you need it as en environment variable do as follows:

```
environment:
   - TE_STR_FILE: /run/secrets/sec-str
```

This will set TE_STR to the contents of your secret.

Comment: It dose not map the value of that file to the TE_STR environment. How to debug it?

Comment: You are right, it should be ':' not '='. I corrected the answer.